# How correct set PropertyPath

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, binding

How correct add PropertyPath ?

I need binding usercontrol DataContext to DataContext, TwoWay.

```
    var binding = new Binding()
                          {
                              Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                              Source = ((FrameworkElement)sender),
                              Path = new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty)
                          };
    binding.Source = ((FrameworkElement) sender);
    changeImage.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, binding);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("DataContext")
```

Also it would help if you will say what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Is it possible to set the PropertyPath to a property of an element?
Like "Example.Name"?
Edit: Nvm. It works with the dot. Only tried with "/" like the ResourceLoader wants it.

Answer (score 1):

`PropertyPath` has a string consructor, which takes the property path as follows:

```
  var binding = new Binding()
                {
                   Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                   Source = ((FrameworkElement)sender),
                   Path = new PropertyPath("DataContext")
                };
```

Alternatively, `Binding` has a constructor which will create a `PropertyPath` from the gives string argument:

```
  var binding = new Binding("DataContext")
                {
                   Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                   Source = ((FrameworkElement)sender)
                };
```